# Load google charts in ember-cli project

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ember.js

I tried to load google chart example in the handlebar template as follows

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
<br>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
{{outlet}}
```

in the console, I got following error,

```
VM15593:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at <anonymous>:4:7
at TreeConstruction.insertBefore (ember.debug.js:50096)
at ElementStack.appendText (ember.debug.js:44985)
at TextOpcode.evaluate (ember.debug.js:47601)
at VM.execute (ember.debug.js:53440)
at Object.render (ember.debug.js:53014)
at RootState.render (ember.debug.js:11335)
at runInTransaction (ember.debug.js:22298)
at InteractiveRenderer._renderRoots (ember.debug.js:11600)
at InteractiveRenderer._renderRootsTransaction (ember.debug.js:11638)
```

What should be done to avoid this error?

Is there any different method to load google charts in ember-cli projects inside template files.

Comment: @kumkanillam, Hope you could help

Comment: I haven't done this before. but normally we don't write script code in `hbs` file. so move this  `charts/loader.js` file inclusion in `index.html`. and create component and inside `didInsertElement` hook method you can write stuff required after component DOM is ready. any how I would strongly encourage you to read [ember-guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)

Comment: @kumkanillam, can you please elaborate the steps regarding use of components.
am new to this.

Comment: @kumkanillam,
Thanks again man, i tried and somehow it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to @kumkanillam,

As per his instructions I first added the script code, to load the charts/loader.js, in the index.html file under App folder,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Then I created a component called ggl-chrt using following command line

```
ember g component ggl-chrt
```

then inside the ggl-chrt.js file under components inserted following code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
didInsertElement() {
google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages':['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
 }
   });
```

then inside ggl-chrt.hbs file, inserted following code:

```
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
{{yield}}
```

then inside the main template file, inserted following code:

```
{{ggl-chrt}}
{{outlet}}
```

[final output obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKY2M.jpg)